# Background Loop in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I'm not sure of the best way to go about this in Node.js (MEAN).  Basically, I am making a game prototype, which will use node as a http server.  I also need to have a constantly running game loop which does work on the Mongo database.  How should I go about this?

Basically,  I need to run code independently of user driven events. Is setInterval() and then an event emit() a good way to do it in Node?

Comment: The answer what would be a 'good' way to handle this, I think, depends on what you need the loop to be running for.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() will work fine, if you are using HTML 5 Canvas to make game just make another canvas to move Background below your original game this will prevent in any interfere with your game.
You can use clearInterval when you want to stop the loop but take care that fps for smooth transition.